# Passing Arrays back to main body

Tags: c++

I am pondering upon available functions in the net for my optimization project.. I have stumbled upon an available code by Bateesh and i found it very useful. But I want to slightly modify his code such that

**instead from printing the output, it will be transferred in my main body to be used in the next process.

How do i do it? I have new in C++ so any suggestions will help. I am currently reading about passing arrays but i am dazed by the new ideas.

Thank you.

```
    // Program to print all combination of size r in an array of size n
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void combinationUtil(int arr[], int n, int r, int count, int data[], int i);

// Needed for qsort.  See http://w...content-available-to-author-only...s.com/reference/cstdlib/qsort/
int compare (const void * a, const void * b)
{
    return ( *(int*)a - *(int*)b );
}

// The main function that prints all combinations of size r
// in arr[] of size n. This function mainly uses combinationUtil()
void printCombination(int arr[], int n, int r)
{
    // A temporary array to store all combination one by one
    int data[r];

    // Sort array to handle duplicates
    qsort (arr, n, sizeof(int), compare);

    // Print all combination using temprary array 'data[]'
    combinationUtil(arr, n, r, 0, data, 0);
}

/* arr[]  ---> Input Array
   n      ---> Size of input array
   r      ---> Size of a combination to be printed
   index  ---> Current index in data[]
   data[] ---> Temporary array to store current combination
   i      ---> index of current element in arr[]     */
void combinationUtil(int arr[], int n, int r, int index, int data[], int i)
{
    // Current cobination is ready, print it
    if (index == r)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<r; j++)
            printf("%d ",data[j]);
        printf("\n");
        return;
    }

    // When no more elements are there to be put
    if (i >= n)
        return;

    // current is included, put next at next location
    data[index] = arr[i];
    combinationUtil(arr, n, r, index+1, data, i+1);

    // Remove duplicates
    while (arr[i] == arr[i+1])
        i++;

    // current is excluded, replace it with next (Note that
    // i+1 is passed, but index is not changed)
    combinationUtil(arr, n, r, index, data, i+1);
}

// Driver program to test above functions
int main()
{
    int arr[] = {1, 2, 1, 3, 1};
    int r = 3;
    int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
    printCombination(arr, n, r);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use `std::array` or `std::vector` instead, to pass arrays around as you like.

Comment: Thank you. I will read about it.

Comment: [Here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) is a good resource for reading.

Comment: @JemEripol `qsort (arr, n, sizeof(int), compare);`  -- Stop this and use `std::sort`

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, does this have specific effect on my program? Thank you.

Comment: @JemEripol -- Possibly.  `std::sort` is faster, is typesafe, and it is C++.  There is no need for a `compare` function, casting all over the place, etc.  Also `int data[r];` is not valid C++.

Comment: @JemEripol Also stay away from implementations using recursion. These won't work for larger arrays.

Comment: Things will go easier for you if you don't use C compatibility features such as C-style arrays and qsort , they have weird behaviour compared to normal C++ features

Comment: @JemEripol -- Also, change the number type from `int` to `double`.  You will see that all of the sorting code using `qsort` doesn't work correctly, and causes undefined behavor.   You now have to write another `compare` function that converts the `void*` to `double*`.  So for each type, you're writing comparison functions -- that's crazy, but that's the way `C` works.  Using `C++` and `std::sort`, there is no issue since `std::sort.` is typesafe and will sort correctly when given types that can be compared using `<`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Do not use arrays at all

I am not going to answer the question you asked, as I consider raw arrays bad in most situations. Even more so if they are passed around (and that is what you are asking for).

C++ does, however, provide alternatives to raw arrays ([`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) and [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) comes to mind). I would recommend to prefere these over raw arrays unless you are writing a container yourself. They are quite solid performance wise.

---

## Do use C++ standard library functions

If I understand you correctly, you are trying to display all possible permutations of the unique values in a given collection of numbers. You could do this using some C++ library functions:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
  // Create vector
  std::vector<int> v { 1, 2, 1, 3, 1 };

  // Sort vector
  std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());

  // Move all duplicate entries to the end of the vector
  auto it = std::unique(v.begin(), v.end());

  // Trim vector so that the duplicates are no longer contained
  v.resize(std::distance(v.begin(), it));

  // Iterate as long as the function can rearrange the objects as a
  // lexicographicaly greater permutation
  do
  {
    // Print all elements in the vector
    for(auto i : v)
      std::cout << i << " ";

    // Add new line character and flush output
    std::cout << std::endl;

  } while(std::next_permutation(v.begin(),v.end()));

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1 2 3 
1 3 2 
2 1 3 
2 3 1 
3 1 2 
3 2 1
```

Comment: I think the biggest thing is that all you need to change is `int` to `double` and the code still works.  That concept is totally lost if `qsort` were used.

Comment: This one is good sir for permutations. But i only need combinations functions so must fix this a bit. I cannot fully understand everything well, but your ideas help lighten me up. Thank you so much.

Comment: @JemEripol Could you give an example of expected output for some given input? I still don't get what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you for all your replies. I should close the thread because i found an easier method to do my output using VBA, this time. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

You can return an array by changing the return type to `std::vector<std::string>` in function `printCombination`. Since `combinationUtil()` is called recursive hence it would be good idea to pass a reference of `std::vector<std::string>` variable from `printCombination` function and let it be filled by `combinationUtil()`. Finally you can return that variable from `printCombination` and make it available to `main()`.

Comment: Oh, i can understand this a bit. I will give you feedback on my work after a while. Thank you. I actually wanted to pass the results into a 2D array.. is it still possible?

Comment: @JemEripol Sure, for 2D arrays use `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`.