# Why doesn't C++ support range based for loop for dynamic arrays?

Tags: c++

Why doesn't C++ support range based for loop over dynamic arrays?  That is, something like this:

```
int* array = new int[len];
for[] (int i : array) {};
```

I just invented the `for[]` statement to rhyme with `new[]` and `delete[]`.  As far as I understand, the runtime has the size of the array available (otherwise `delete[]` could not work) so in theory, range based for loop could also be made to work.  What is the reason that it's not made to work?

Comment: The root of your question really is why C++ doesn't allow you to retrieve the size of a dynamically allocated array. For that, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36471101/c-doesnt-tell-you-the-size-of-a-dynamic-array-but-why (read the highest voted answer, not the accepted one)

Comment: You should change the name `array` for `pointer` and everything will be clearer.

Comment: If you want to conveniently iterate over something like an array, you could use one of the c++ std library's containers. [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) and [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) comes to mind. See [my answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44985585/4486783) as an example.

Comment: I hope this is a language-lawyer question. In real code, you'd just use `std::vector` and be done with it...

Comment: Closely related: `dynarray`-s. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/17353873/841108

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Range-based for loop on a dynamic array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15904896/range-based-for-loop-on-a-dynamic-array)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ doesn't tell you the size of a dynamic array. But why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36471101/c-doesnt-tell-you-the-size-of-a-dynamic-array-but-why)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ```
> int* array = new int[len];
> for[] (int i : array) {}
> ```

There are several points which must be addressed; I'll tackle them one at a time.

> Does the run-time knows the size of the array?

In certain conditions, it must. As you pointed out, a call to `delete[]` will call the destructor of each element (in reserve order) and therefore *must* know how many there are.

However, by not specifying that the number of elements must be known, and accessible, the C++ standard allows an implementation to omit it whenever the call to the destructor is not required (`std::is_trivially_destructible<T>::value` evaluates to `true`).

> Can the run-time distinguish between pointer and array?

In general, no.

When you have a pointer, it could point to anything:

- a single item, or an item in an array,
- the first item in an array, or any other,
- an array on the stack, or an array on the heap,
- just an array, or an array part of a larger object.

This is the reason what `delete[]` exists, and using `delete` here would be incorrect. With `delete[]`, you the user state: *this pointer points to the first item of a heap-allocated array*.

The implementation can then assume that, for example, in the 8 bytes preceding this first item it can find the size of the array. Without you guaranteeing this, those 8 bytes could be anything.

> Then, why not go all the way and create `for[] (int i : array)`?

There are two reasons:

1. As mentioned, today an implementation can elide the size on a number of elements; with this new `for[]` syntax, it would no longer be possible on a per-type basis.
2. It's not worth it.

Let us be honest, `new[]` and `delete[]` are relics of an older time. They are incredibly awkward:

- the number of elements has to be known in advance, and cannot be changed,
- the elements must be default constructible, or otherwise C-ish,

and unsafe to use:

- the number of elements is inaccessible to the user.

There is generally no reason to use `new[]` and `delete[]` in modern C++. Most of the times a `std::vector` should be preferred; in the few instances where the capacity is superfluous, a `std::dynarray` is still better (because it keeps track of the size).

Therefore, without a valid reason to keep using these statements, there is no motivation to include new semantic constructs specifically dedicated to handling them.

And should anyone be motivated enough to make such a proposal:

- the inhibition of the current optimization, a violation of C++ philosophy of "You don't pay for what you don't use", would likely be held against them,
- the inclusion of new syntax, when modern C++ proposals have gone to great lengths to avoid it as much as possible (to the point of having a library defined `std::variant`), would also likely be held against them.

I recommend that you simply use `std::vector`.

Comment: Sadly it appears that `std::dynarray` isn't a thing any more.

Answer (score 14):

> What is the reason that it's not made to work?

A range based loop like

```
 for(auto a : y) {
     // ...
 }
```

is just syntactic sugar for the following expression

```
 auto endit = std::end(y);
 for(auto it = std::begin(y); it != endit; ++it) {
     auto a = *it;
     // ...
 }
```

Since `std::begin()` and `std::end()` cannot be used with a plain pointer, this can't be applied with a pointer allocated with `new[]`.

> As far as I understand, the runtime has the size of the array available (otherwise `delete[]` could not work)

How `delete[]` keeps track of the memory block that was allocated with `new[]` (which isn't necessarily the same size as was specified by the user), is a completely different thing and the compiler most probably doesn't even know how exactly this is implemented.

Comment: @BalintLaczay The size is somehow theoretically known at runtime, at least it's the minimum that was specified with `new[]`. But it's usually the size of a bigger memory block. The only information that will be kept by the runtime is the pointer of the allocated memory block. This highly depends on the OS specific implementation of memory management.

Comment: Thank you! Can I recommend that you expand the second part of your answer by:

`delete[]` only needs to know the size if it has to make actual destructor calls. For an array of `int`s, the compiler might not even store the size anywhere, just rely on some underlying memory management to free the memory on delete[]. Thus, supporting the `for[]` suggested by the OP would potentially add some overhead by forcing the compiler to store the size even in situations where no destructor calls are need.

Maybe also remove the first part of your answer, it does not contribute to answering my question

Comment: @BalintLaczay I'm not going to change my answer, it is fine as is. It's you who still seems to confuse arrays with pointers. There's no need that an _extra size info_ is stored for raw arrays, this is known at compile time.

Comment: The runtime only tracks the size if the object has a destructor to call for `delete[]`. Otherwise it doesn't. `delete[]` doesn't get called for deleting a `new char[x]`; `delete` does.

Comment: @BalintLaczay: You are fishing in the wrong waters: The array doesn't have to be allocated with `new[]` in the first place! It could be allocated with `malloc` or `alloca`, or even be returned from another `extern "C"` library (which might have its own runtime library!), so there is no way to know if there even is some size info, or where it is if it exists.

Comment: Minor point, your syntactic sugar is off: `std::end` is only called once in a range-based for loop.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Thanks for noticing.

Answer (score 6):

When you have this:

```
int* array = new int[len];
```

The problem here is that your variable called `array` is not an array at all. It is a *pointer*. That means it only contains the *address* of **one** object (in this case the first element of the array created using `new`).

For *range based for* to work the compiler needs **two** addresses, the beginning and the end of the array.

So the problem is the compiler does not have enough information to do this:

```
// array is only a pointer and does not have enough information
for(int i : array)
{
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is not related to dynamic arrays, it is more general. Of course for dynamic arrays there exists somewhere the size to be able to call destructors (but remember that standard doesn't says anything about that, just that calling `delete []` works as intended).

The problem is with pointers in general as given a pointer you can't tell if it correspond to any kind of...what?

Arrays decay to pointers but given a pointer what can you say?

Comment: @RustyX: Not sure I understand your last sentence. You *can* iterate over an actual array type.

Answer (score 1):

`array` is not an array, but a pointer and there's no information about the **size** of the "array". So, compiler can not deduce `begin` and `end` of this array.

See the syntax of [range based for](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) loop:

```
{
   auto && __range = range_expression ; 
   for (auto __begin = begin_expr, __end = end_expr; 
   __begin != __end; ++__begin) { 
   range_declaration = *__begin; 
   loop_statement 
   } 
}
```

> **range_expression** - any expression that represents a suitable sequence
>   (either an array or an object for which begin and end member functions
>   or free functions are defined, see below) or a braced-init-list.

`auto` works at compile time.So, `begin_expr` and `end_expr` doesn't at deduct runtime.

Comment: But why?  Could `for[]` define `begin_expr` to be `range_expression` and `end_expr` to be `range_expression + size`, where `size` is the size of the array (as used in `delete[]`)?

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that, given only the value of the pointer `array`, the compiler (and your code) has no information about what it points at.   The only thing known is that `array` has a value which is the address of a single `int`.

It could point at the first element of a statically allocated array.   It could point at an element in the middle of a dynamically allocated array.   It could point at a member of a data structure.    It could point at an element of an array that is within a data structure.   The list goes on.

Your code will make ASSUMPTIONS about what the pointer points at.   It may assume it is an array of 50 elements.   Your code may access the value of `len`, and assume `array` points at the (first element of) an array of `len` elements.    If your code gets it right, all works as intended.   If your code gets it wrong (e.g.  accessing the 50th element of an array with 5 elements) then the behaviour is simply undefined.   It is undefined because the possibilities are endless - the book-keeping to keep track of what an arbitrary pointer ACTUALLY points at (beyond the information that there is an `int` at that address) would be enormous.

You're starting with the ASSUMPTION that `array` points at the result from `new int[len]`.   But that information is not stored in the value of `array` itself, so the compiler has no way to work back to a value of `len`.    That would be needed for your "range based" approach to work.

While, yes, given `array = new int[len]`, the machinery invoked by `delete [] array` will work out that `array` has `len` elements, and release them.    But `delete [] array` also has undefined behaviour if `array` results from something other than a `new []` expression.  Even

```
  int *array = new int;
  delete [] array;
```

gives undefined behaviour.    The "runtime" is not required to work out, in this case, that `array` is actually the address of a single dynamically allocated `int` (and not an actual array).   So it is not required to cope with that.